# compiling fortran to c on mac

Tags: c, macos, fortran

I have fortan files that I need to compile on mac, and all the installations of f2c that I found
seem to be corrupted. 
I tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://www.webmo.net/support/fortran_osx.html), but it shows an error '*cannot execute binary file*'. If someone can point me to a better installation, or help me fix the problem with the current install that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not install `gfortran`, part of `GCC`, which runs sweetly on a Mac ?  I promise you that you are entering a world of pain if you pursue the use of `f2c`; if you doubt me read some of the Qs and As on the topic on this site.

Comment: Is there an issue with installing a real Fortran compiler on MacOS and compiling the code as Fortran code?

Comment: The simplest is with **homebrew**, see https://brew.sh  which would be `brew install gcc`

Comment: If you describe what you did (don't just link instructions), we can try to figure out the specific error. But yeah, using a fortran compiler is better than converting fortran to c.